# Why was the movie The Wicker Man dedicated to Johnny Ramone?

Tags: credits, the-wicker-man-2006

At the end of the movie The Wicker Man (the Nicholas Cage version not the original) after the fade to black and before the credits there is a screen that says "For Johnny Ramone" What was the reason behind dedicated this movie to one of the founding fathers of punk rock?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMDB page for the movie's [trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0450345/trivia) lists that:
*The film is dedicated to late musician Johnny Ramone, who introduced Nicolas Cage to Robin Hardy's original The Wicker Man.*

Answer (score 5):

Johnny Ramone's [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Ramone#Posthumous_honors) page states:

> In 2006, the remake of the horror film The Wicker Man was dedicated to
>   Johnny Ramone's memory, as he was a close friend of the film's
>   producer and star, Nicolas Cage

Comment: Oh my goodness, Cage also produced that monstrosity?  It would explain why no one put the brakes on it, I guess.